# Как в react сделать background-image если картинка в props?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

В react я получаю картинку с API и мне нужно сделать ее как background-image.Могу ли я как то передать ее в css или есть другие способи так сделать?
Пробовал вот так `<div className="" style={{background-image: {this.props.filmPoster}}}>`,но так не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `inline` стилях в React если имена какого то CSS свойство больше одного слово как у вас `background-image`  надо имена CSS стилей писать слитно правильно будет **backgroundImage**.

Также надо `url` указывать для этого CSS свойства.

Я сделал небольшой пример отправляю картинку с одного компонента в другой как `props`.

```
export default function App() {
  const [state] = useState(
    "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg"
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Image sendUrl={state} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Компонент Image

```
class Image extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.sendUrl})`,
          width: "500px",
          height: "250px"
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

[**Codesandbox тут**](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-meitner-bydbp)

Comment: Спасибо огромное)

Comment: @Volodumr всегда пожалуйста :)